# Using DataOutputStream in Java gives some Chinese output

Tags: java, string, file-io, utf

I was using `DataOutputStream` in Java today, but it gave me a Chinese output, that was absolutely NOT what I had expected... Can someone please spot the error in the code?

```
private void generateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    textToSet="       Student Information";
    textToSet=textToSet+"\nName\t: "+TitleBox.getSelectedItem()+" "+FirstNameField.getText()+" "+LastNameField.getText();
    textToSet=textToSet+"\nClass\t: "+ClassField.getText();
    TextArea.setText(textToSet);
}

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try{
        File f=new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\ID Card.txt");
        DataOutputStream fs=new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f)));
        fs.writeUTF(textToSet);
        Desktop d=Desktop.getDesktop();
        d.open(f);
        fs.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`TitleBox` is a `JComboBox`, `FirstNameField`, `LastNameField`, and `ClassField` are `JTextField`'s. `TextArea` is a `JTextArea`.

When I choose "Mr." in `TitleBox`, type "Man" in `FirstNameField`, "Ly" in `LastNameField` and "7th" in `ClassField`, I get the output:

```
       Student Information
Name    : Mr. Man Ly
Class   : 7th
```

in the TextArea, but in the file, IDCard.txt, I get the output:

```
㠀†††匠畴敤瑮䤠普牯慭楴湯上浡॥›牍‮慍⁮祌䌊慬獳㨉㜠桴
```

`textToSet` is a `String` variable defined in the public scope... Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there something wrong with the `writeUTF()` code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `writeUTF` method includes header data (your so called chinese characters) about how long a String it's going to write (2 bytes, so 0-65535). You can only use `readUTF` to read that data properly, it's not meant for general text writing.

Just use a regular `BufferedWriter.write(String str)` to write the text instead.